# When can self == None

Tags: python, nonetype, truthiness

I am looking at a snippet `if not self:` in [an answer to another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146386/66848) which implements `__nonzero__()`.

This gets me wondering: apart from `__nonzero__()` returning `False` or the trivial local assignment `self = None`, are there other situations, in which the conditional `if not self` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Python's documentation on [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) or [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a [`__bool__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method that returns `False` or a [`__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object.

In the code you reference, [`__nonzero__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) is the Python 2 equivalent of Python 3's `__bool__()`.

So, an alternative to the `__bool__()` method in your question could be something like:

```
class Lenny:

    def __len__(self):
        return 0 if self.value == '#' else len(self.children)
```

**Note:** None of this has anything much to do with the title of your question: "When can self == None". *Equality* (whether to `None` or to anything else) is a different concept from *truth value*, and is defined by the [`__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method:

```
class Nonelike:

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == None
```